# Adding Basemap to ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, 3d-analyst, arcscene, basemap

I want to add a basemap under my 3D bar chart of density. I tried a lot by couldn't add the basemap in ArcScene. I want a map like the one below.

[image]

Comment: @PolyGeo I have added an answer, however I was unsuccessful in finding ArcGIS Pro documentation about how to add a basemap.  Seems like it might have been overlooked as it's standard/basic functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can't add basemaps into ArcScene

from [Adding an ArcGIS Online basemap into ArcGlobe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/adding-an-arcgis-online-basemap-into-arcglobe.htm)

> Note that none of the online basemaps will work in ArcScene.

You could work around this by clipping or exporting a basemap as an image and adding the image to your ArcScene.

I would, however, recommend you look into using **ArcGIS Pro** rather than ArcScene.  ArcGIS Pro will allow you to make use of basemaps, and can be used as a local scene (similar to ArcScene) or as a global scene (similar to ArcGlobe), as well as a 2D map view.  In fact you can do all three at the same time within the same ArcGIS Pro document.

The screenshot below shows a local scene in ArcGIS Pro, and the option to add/change basemaps.

[image]

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply .but I exported the  base map of desired area from arc globe but that doesn't set in the exact location.I did geo reference the image but nothing happened. Btw I don't have any access to Arc gis pro.thanks

Comment: @Anika - clip it in ArcMap which should include spatial reference and then import into ArcScene

Answer (score 1):

Export your base map from ArcMap as GeoTiff.

***File->Export Map->Save as type (TIFF)->Format tab under 'options'->check 'Write Geo TIFF Tags***.

This image could be added to arcscene.

It works fine.

Regards

Comment: This looks like a possible edit to the first answer, rather than a new answer.  The first answer tells us `You could work around this by clipping or exporting a basemap as an image and adding the image to your ArcScene.`